# Browser to Android app to browser

Tags: android, android-intent, callback, android-browser

I have an android app that is opened through a intent on a webpage. This app does few things and when it finishes I want to come back on browser on another page.
I can do that but it opens a new tab while I would like to change page without open a new tab.

This is what I do:

```
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(callbackUrl));
            startActivity(browserIntent);
            MainActivity.this.finish();
```

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Show the code that produces this. Each question should be accompanied with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any information how to change data in the original browser (and it doesn't seem a reasonable action) but here what you can do:

- On your webpage generate a `session_id` (user_id/whatever_id) and store it somewhere (cookies, local storage, or just in memory)
- When launching intent pass this id along (`<a href="my.special.scheme://session_id">`)
- Get this id in the app like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2958870/3344612)
- Then you'll have to make a simple web app which will save a pair: id - URL and will invalidate it after first get request
- When you want get back to browser and redirect send to the mentioned server this URL (e.g. `myserver.net/store?id=<session_id_here>&url=google.com`)
- Then simply 'go back' to browser
- When your webpage regains active get this and ask server if there are any URL for it (e.g. `myserver.net/get?id=<session_id_here>`)
- Get this url and go to it (`window.location.href = <url>`)

Comment: It can be an option. I thought of a job that waits for a response from the android app and when it comes the page is reloaded on the link I want. I don't like it very much I still hope for a better solution. Thanks.

Comment: @Teivaz  from your answer 
" When you want get back to browser and redirect send to the mentioned server this URL (e.g. myserver.net/store?id=<session_id_here>&url=google.com)
Then simply 'go back' to browser" 
-- using it will open new tab in browser . is there any solution to get target on same tab, a refresh will not be issue there if needed.

Comment: @Khushi over the past years many things have changed, you might be better off asking this as a separate question